# How to get sum off all values associated with an id in GCP Metrics explorer - MQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I want to execute MQL (metric query language) to get sum of all values from "metric.size" column which have the same "metric.id".

[the table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w21FV.png)

It should be grouped by id, and size column to be the sum of all the size values for matching id, and this within a certain time range.

In SQL it would look something like below:
select id, sum(size) from "metric" group by id where ts is bigger X & less than Y

I have tried many variation of the below command; using within, every, window with no luck.

`fetch k8s_container | metric 'logging.googleapis.com/user/ingestion-info' | group_by [metric.tenantId], sum(metric.size) | every 13h`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Also i have tried solutions in the below links:
[Unable to collect data from metric query language MQL - GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728245/unable-to-collect-data-from-metric-query-language-mql-gcp)
[GCP MQL query: getting metrics/minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893326/gcp-mql-query-getting-metrics-minute)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to turn the column you want to aggregate into a `value` column. `metric` and `resource` columns are used in the first argument of `group_by` operation.

```
fetch k8s_container
| metric 'logging.googleapis.com/user/ingestion-info'
| value [value.size: metric.size]
| group_by [metric.tenantId], sum(value.size)
| every 13h
```

BTW, looks like there is no value exported in your table. If the `metric.size` is the info you want to monitor, I recommend you define it as the value of the metric. `logging.googleapis.com/user/ingestion_size` or `logging.googleapis.com/user/ingestion-info/size` might be more readable as a metric name.

Comment: Thank you for the response @cheng-hou
my ingestion-info metric has 5 labels which include both size and tenantId values. 
also based on my testing sum(metric.size) does the same thing as setting the value.size and then getting the sum of that. 
I was able to get some data thats matching my actual logs using the below:
`
fetch k8s_container
| metric 'logging.googleapis.com/user/ingestion-info'
| group_by [metric.tenantId], sum(metric.size)
| within 1h
| window 1h
`
but now problem is the inconsistency of the "within" and the time range doesn't work properly when using date literal

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "within" problem?